# php reading and associative array from multiple database records

Tags: php, echo, associative-array

I know there have been many questions on associative arrays, but I haven't seen one that explains what I have to do to extract the data from this way of creating one. Assume that I have selected multiple records from the same field in the database.

```
    while ($Row = mysql_fetch_array($mySQLData))
    {
    $assocarraydata[]= array('field1'=>$Row["field1"]);
    };
```

I know I can do it this way using the index:

```
    //Put Data into an regular array
    while ($Row = mysql_fetch_array($mySQLData))
    {
    $field1[] = $Row[field1];
    }

    echo $field1[1];
```

But I don't know how to do it for the associative array in the first example. Can someone help?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you trying to get an associative array that represents your row in array($field => $value) form? Have you tried [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) ?

Comment: Neither way is precise. And both example are not using associative array, they are just indexed array.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array()` can do both what `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and `mysql_fetch_row()` do, and that's the default behaviour.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, but are trying to organize the arrays by key? e.g. `$assocarraydata['field1'][] = $Row['field1'];`

Comment: I'm nt trying to get or create an associative array. In fact from the comments I'm thinking that I've misused the word. In the second example I am able to print the data (the value) found in the field at record 2 in the database because I specified the index. I could have used a loop and printed all values. But I have no idea how to do that when I create the array in example 1. How do I identify(by index or other) and echo the values in example1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to figure out what you're asking, but if the question is how to produce the same result from the first example, the answer is:

```
// echo the value of field1 from the second (index 1) row of data
echo $assocarraydata[1]['field1'];
```

Comment: so I would still need an index

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an index in the resulting array - otherwise you won't be able to access different rows. Just think of the indexes as row numbers:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    $array[] = $row;
```

... and then you can access your data like this:

`$array[0]['field1']` - first row, column 'field1'
`$array[5]['field5']` - sixth row, column 'field5'

... etc.